# Regarding @synthesize in iOS6+

Tags: ios, objective-c

Eg:

```
//Myclass.h
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

//MyClass.m
//@synthesize name = _name
```

So I know that we don't need to use `@synthesize` any more from iOS6+. The compiler automatically creates getters and setters for me.

1. But I don't understand is when to use `self.name = @"Testing"` and when to use `_name = @"Testing"`?
2. Should `_name = @"Testing"` be ever used?
3. If yes, when? When should an iVAR be used at all?
4. Also if i want to write my own getter and setter do i need to write `@synthesize` or can i just write my getter and setter?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The basic guidelines are outlined in the [Practical Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) section of the _Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide._ BTW, you should generally avoid writing your own accessor methods unless you absolutely need to. The vast majority of the time, the synthesized accessor methods do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you only use instance variables in init methods, getters and setters, and dealloc. There are exceptions of course, but this is a good rule of thumb.

If you write both your own getter **and** setter (or in the case of a readonly property and you write the getter), you have to synthesize your property yourself. In all other cases, the property is auto-synthesized.

Comment: If you are writing the getter and/or the setter, then the property should not be synthesized. It's an error to have the compiler generate two (pair of) methods with the same name.

Comment: @H2CO3: The compiler will not create an instance variable if you write both setter and getter (or just the getter if it's a readonly property).

Comment: I know. That doesn't mean you should synthesize it. Synthesizing != declaring an ivar (which should be done in this case).

Comment: @H2CO3: So what happens if I do synthesize in this case? Isn't it just going to create the backing ivar for the property, without generating the methods since I provide them myself?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, that is exactly what happens in this case.

Comment: @Scott AFAIK `@synthesize` generates method definitions, but perhaps `clang` got smarter since last time I checked this.

Comment: `@synthesize` generates method definitions (if necessary) *and* the ivar.

Comment: So I guess then the question is: is it better to explicitly declare the ivar yourself, or have `@synthesize` create it for you? I'd say have `@synthesize` do it (less work when you remove one of the methods), but there may be reasons why doing it yourself is a better approach.

Comment: @Scott I think in that scenario it's better to use `@synthesize`, because it makes your intent explicit.

Comment: If you create an app from the "Master-Detail + Core Data" template in Xcode, the read-only properties "managedObjectContext, ..." are synthesized and have custom getters. - This is just an example of course.

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why i should use iVar in init? or it just a thumb rule. I usually just use self.variable name in init methods.

Comment: @MehulMittal As discussed in [Access Instance Variables Directly from Initializer Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5) the concern is that you may have a custom setters (in your class or some future subclass) or have some KVC notification that assume the object is fully initialized (i.e. not in the process of being constructed in `init` or ripped down in `dealloc`). Using ivars ensures no unintended consequences.